# Create loop, which adds up 72 elements of a 2016 element array and stores the sum in an element in a new array

Tags: javascript

At the moment it always takes the same 72 elements. How can I manage that after each round it takes the next 72 values e.g. 73 - 144 than 145 - 217 etc.?

```
    var houseconsumtion_week = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    
    // should loop 28 times, houseconsumtion.length = Array containing 2016 elements
    for (var j = 0; j < houseconsumtion.length; j+=72) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
            sum += houseconsumtion[i];
        }
        houseconsumtion_week.push(sum);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder what would be the value of `i + j` in the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

You can access the element at index `i + j` each time.

```js
for (var j = 0; j < houseconsumtion.length; j += 72) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
        sum += houseconsumtion[i + j];
    }
    houseconsumtion_week.push(sum);
}
```